# How can I push a nx monorepo project to a remote branch?

Tags: git, monorepo

I'm need to push a react nx monorepo project to a remote development branch.
To do that, I've cloned the repo, created my nx monorepo project and called it "core" . After that, I did "git add core/", commit, and push it  "git push -u origin main".

However, I did it in the wrong way because my boss said "You've committed the entire folder again, you have to have the git inside the core folder and only commit what's in the folder".

What am I missing here? How can I have a git inside de core folder (the folder created with nx already have a git) and only commit what's in inside?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I have a git inside the `core` folder

You would need to do a `git init .` inside the `core` folder, and open your Visual Studio from that folder

```
cd /ath/to/core
git init .
code -n .
```

That way, your Visual Studio Code would see only that repository, even if [`nx` created one above the core folder](https://nx.dev/more-concepts/why-monorepos).

That means you would create a nested Git repository inside another one, which is not exactly a best practice (`core/` content history would be ignored by the `nx` monorepo), but would comply with your boss' expectations.

A better approach would be to make sure core/ *is* the nx monorepo.